# A problem with table of contents

Tags: titles

I made a document which contains a abstract, my problem is when I click on the title of abstract in the table of contents it goes to the cover page and not to the page of abstract.
here is my code :

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[some]{background}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[english,french]{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,%
    citecolor=black,%
    filecolor=black,%
    linkcolor=black,%
    urlcolor=black} 


\makeatletter
\newenvironment{resume}{%
    \cleardoublepage
    \null\vfil
    \@beginparpenalty\@lowpenalty
    \begin{center}%
        \bfseries\Large {abstract}
        \@endparpenalty\@M
\end{center}}%
{\par\vfil\null}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\newgeometry{left=1cm,right=4cm}
\begin{center}
    {\Huge My Title Page}
\end{center}
\end{titlepage}
\newpage
\begin{resume} 
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\textnormal{\textit{abstract}}}
    An abstract is a brief summary of a research article, thesis, review, conference proceeding or any in-depth analysis of a particular subject or discipline, and is often used to help the reader quickly ascertain the paper's purpose. When used, an abstract always appears at the beginning of a manuscript, acting as the point-of-entry for any given scientific paper or patent application. Abstracting and indexing services for various academic disciplines are aimed at compiling a body of literature for that particular subject.
\end{resume}
    \tableofcontents
\chapter{Chapter one}
\section{Section one}
\section{Section two}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\phantomsection \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\textnormal{\textit{abstract}}}` should correct that.

Comment: I replaced the line that you gave me and everything is ok. Thank you very mutch @leandriis

Answer (score 1):

I'm turning leandriis's comment into an answer because there isn't one.

Use this:

```
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\textnormal{\textit{abstract}}}
```